# Edit/delete calendar event in Android API < 4.0 - should I do it?

Tags: android, android-calendar

My app has a built in feature for creating in-app reminders, and it needs to support at least API 8 (Android 2.2). There is no problem adding a calendar event, but the problem begins when the user edits the reminder date in-app and expects that the calendar event related to the app data will change too.

Also, the app data is synchronised with a server, so I maybe should delete all old events from my app when syncing and re-create the new ones. But to do that I'll need to find the events that have been created by my app and I'm not entirely sure how I can find them (maybe by time and event title?)

From what I understand, editing or deleting calendar events is not officially supported in Android versions prior to 4.0, so it might not work on all devices, etc. Should I just tell my client that we should just support events in Android 4.0+?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I just tell my client that we should just support events in Android 4.0+?

IMHO, yes.

Comment: I'd like to tell our clients the same, but as long as there are ~30% Gingerbread devices out there, they don't want to hear that :-/

Comment: @Ridcully: Reliability of the undocumented/unsupported approaches, such as is discussed in the other answer, is low. IMHO, you are better served in having a reliable feature set that you can support than an unreliable feature set that, when users complain about the unreliability, all you can do is shrug your shoulders.

Answer (score 1):

Note Questoins like `should I ... yes/no` are likely opinion based question that belongs to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ and are likely to be closed on http://stackoverflow.com.

If your question is how to use calender in android versions below 4.0 you can look at
[Jim Blackler's Accessing the internal calendar database inside Google Android applications](http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151)

where you basically query contentproviders where url and fields may differ depinding on manufacturer and android version (ie `content://calendarEx` or `content://calendar` or `content://com.android.calendar`). This is slightly different from [the official android 4 api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Calendars.html).

So you have to encapsulate this logic yourself and be prepared that it will not work on every prior andriod 4.0.